# Is "qui" as a question word always singular?

Tags: accord, questions, interrogative, pronoms-interrogatifs

English seems to be inconsistent on this. In both of the following sentences, "Who" is a question word, that is a subject, that is "plural" (ie, "who" will be "replaced" in the answer by more than one person), but one sentence sounds correct with "is", and the other sounds more correct with "are":

> Who's (= "who **is**") coming to the party? *(We expect multiple people to be
>   coming to the party, despite "is" being used!)*
>   Who **are** your best friends?

I don't think I have come across "Qui sont _____?" before. Can you ever start a question sentence with "Qui sont ____ ?"

Comment: There is a false premise in your question, in "who are your best friends?", "who" is not the subject but the "subject complement" (as stated in [this forum](https://forum.thefreedictionary.com/postst154095_Is--who--the-subject-of-the-sentence-.aspx), if you replace "who" with "where", your sentence has still a subject, and its not "where"). That's probably why you are perceiving an inconsistency. This is exactly the same in French (see my answer).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes this is totally possible in French, much as it is in English.

> Who are your best friends ?

would translate to

> Qui **sont** vos meilleurs amis ?

A singular question could be

> Who is here ?

Translating to

> Qui **est** là ?

For the party example, the translation is more complicated.

> Who is coming to the party ?

would actually translate to

> Qui est-ce qui vient à la fête ?

Because in French logic, one must say "Who is it who is coming"

The reason for singular or plural is the same in English and in French. When one knows that the subject is plural, one uses the plural form. Otherwise, when in doubt, one uses the singular form. For "Who is coming to the party ?", the [group of 0 or more people] coming to the party could possibly be singular. So the sentence uses singular.

Comment: Would you also use "Qui sont" for "Who is coming to the party?", too?

Comment: I'm curious why it's "qui vient" for the party question, instead of "qui viennent"; but then again, I dont' know why it's "Who **is** coming to the party?" in English, either. However, I had thought that "Qui est-ce qui" could be shortened to "qui"?

Answer (score 7):

**TL;DR**: dans une question, lorsque « qui » est le sujet, « qui » est considéré comme singulier et le verbe s'accorde en conséquence. Les questions commençant par « Qui sont ... » existent mais alors « qui » n'est pas le sujet.

---

Je ne suis pas d'accord avec la réponse de Vince qui est actuellement acceptée. En particulier avec la phrase conclusive « When one knows that the subject is plural, one uses the plural form. »

En français, lorsque « qui » représente le sujet, « qui » est considéré comme singulier, même lorsque l'on sait pertinemment que plusieurs personnes sont concernées par la question. Par exemple, à l'affirmation « Il y a trois personnes qui ne peuvent pas entrer », on ne demandera pas « Qui ne peuvent pas entrer ? » mais « Qui ne peut pas entrer ? ».

Il faut comprendre que dans une question qui commence par « qui », ce « qui » peut représenter plusieurs choses :

- soit le sujet : « Qui monte dans ma voiture ? ». Dans ce cas on peut toujours remplacer « qui » par « qui est-ce qui » (ou, plus populairement « qui c'est qui »). Si ce remplacement n'est pas possible, alors c'est que « qui » n'est pas le sujet. Comme dit plus haut, qui est alors singulier et le verbe s'accorde avec lui (à la 3ème personne du singulier donc).
- soit le complément d'objet : « Qui déposons-nous à la gare ? ». Dans ce cas on peut soit remplacer « qui » par « qui est-ce que » (ou, plus populairement « qui c'est que »), soit en inversant les mots : « Nous déposons qui à la gare ? ». Si ce remplacement ou cette inversion ne sont pas possibles, alors c'est que « qui » n'est pas le complément d'objet. Le verbe s'accorde avec le sujet et il est donc au pluriel dans cet exemple puisque le sujet est « nous ».

  À noter que « Qui aide Jeanne ? » est ambigu en l'absence de contexte : on ne sait pas si quelqu'un aide Jeanne (« Qui est-ce qui aide Jeanne ? ») ou si Jeanne aide quelqu'un (« Qui Jeanne aide-t-elle ? », « Jeanne aide qui ? »).

  En revanche, « Qui acclament ces gens ? » n'est pas ambigu à l'écrit car du fait du pluriel, « qui » n'est pas le sujet. Mais c'est ambigu à l'oral et l'on dira plutôt « Qui est-ce que ces gens acclament ? » ou  « Ces gens acclament qui ? » ou, plus soutenu, « Qui ces gens acclament-ils ? »
- soit l'attribut, et on en revient à votre question : dans « Qui sont vos meilleurs amis ? », « qui » n'est pas sujet de « sont » mais est l'attribut du sujet qui est en réalité "vos meilleurs amis". Ça devient évident lorsque l'on passe au régime soutenu et que l'on tourne la question ainsi : « Qui vos meilleurs amis sont-ils ? » ou si l'on remplace « Qui » par « Où » (« Où sont vos meilleurs amis ? »). Le verbe s'accorde bien sûr avec le sujet qui est ici un pluriel.

  À noter que dans une question qui commence par « qui est », « qui » n'est pas toujours un attribut, ce peut être le sujet comme par exemple dans « Qui est d'accord ? » ou « Qui est en train de faire du bruit ? ». Dans ce cas bien sûr le verbe est à la 3ème personne du singulier. Si « qui » est un attribut, on doit pouvoir le remplacer par « quel » (à accorder au besoin) qui va rendre la question plus soutenue : « Quels sont vos meilleurs amis ? », « Quelle est cette personne ? ». Si ce remplacement n'est pas possible, alors c'est que « qui » n'est pas un attribut.

Pour conclure, je vais répondre à votre question : on peut commencer une question par « Qui sont ... » mais dans ce cas « qui » n'est pas le sujet de « sont ».

Comment: Oui, bien sûr, le sujet suit le verbe dans *qui suis-je*, *qui es-tu ?*, *qui est-ce ?*, *qui êtes-vous ?*, *qui sommes-nous ?*, *qui sont-ils ?*.